# Predicting fake news or not does'nt work well with new data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
                     content                          label
0   Sainte-Nathalène – Si les scientifiques sonnen...   1
1   Le musicien américano-néerlandais Eddie Van Ha...   0
2   Angela Merkel écoute Emmanuel Macron, lors d’u...   0
3   Analyse. Telle qu’elle a été présentée, dimanc...   0
4   Sur l’esplanade du Trocadéro, à Paris, 24 août...   0
```

The data has 1000 fake news article and 1000 real news article.

I trained model like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], df['label'], test_size=0.20)

# Random forest

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

# Vectorizing and applying TF-IDF

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('model', RandomForestClassifier())
])

# Fitting the model
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Accuracy
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, plot_confusion_matrix
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print("accuracy: {}%".format(round(accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)*100,2)))
```

> accuracy: 95.95%

```
rf_cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction)
print(rf_cm)
```

> [[193  18]  [  0 233]]

So the model is well trained.

I did model.pickle to use the model in Flask.

When I use this model with a new article it always predict a fake article. Even when the article is Real.

model.py in flask app is this:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

news = pd.read_csv('news2.csv')
X = news['content']
y = news['label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

# Random forest

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

# Vectorizing and applying TF-IDF

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('model', RandomForestClassifier())
])

# Fitting the model
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Accuracy
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, plot_confusion_matrix
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print("accuracy: {}%".format(round(accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)*100,2)))

rf_cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction)
print(rf_cm)

#Serialize the file
with open('model.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(pipeline, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

in routes.py I did this:

```
# Receiving the input url from the user and using Web Scraping to extract the news content
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    url = request.get_data(as_text=True)[5:]
    url = urllib.parse.unquote(url)
    article = Article(str(url))
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()
    news = article.summary
    # Passing the news article to the model and returing whether it is Fake or Real
    pred = model.predict([news])
    dic = {1:'Fake',0:'Real'}
    return render_template('home.html', prediction_text='The news is "{}"'.format(dic[pred[0]]))
```

What can be the reason ? How can I have better results with new data using the trained model.

Comment: Does your model in flask correctly label samples from the test data?

Comment: I updated the post with the model.py I did in my flask app. How can I check if the model in flask correctly label samples from the test data ?

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough: Does it work as expected with training or test data, when using flask?

Comment: Yes it works well. Can the reason be I trained my model with not enough data ?

Comment: You can't detect fake news with BOW model. You need to extract facts and check them against truth database.

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov why can't I ?

Comment: Because word order matters. "Trump said Baiden won" and "Baiden said Trump won" are indiscernible form BOW viewpoint, though one may be True and the other not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detecting fake news is difficult. It needs a lot of knowledge about the world, not only about some probability of appearing words. A few years ago, the article 'US president suggested nuking hurricanes' would have clearly been labeled 'fake news' by a lot of people. But today? [Not so sure](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2020-election/live-blog/first-presidential-debate-trump-biden-n1241282/ncrd1241520#blogHeader)...

Your model seem to fit well for your dataset. But does it actually represent your problem? Your model did learn something, but what did it learn? Probably there are certain phrases which occur in the dataset to signify 'real' news, but not in the websites article? Probably the other way round?

Also, did you check if you properly preprocess your data after scraping? Are there still html-tags or similar artefacts in the data? This could also have an effect on the classifier.

But all in all, I would be very impressed by a model learning to detect fake news with just 2000 samples. Even for human experts, fact-checking is a hard task!

Comment: Thank you, so I'm going to find a dataset with 40 000 articles. There are some in Kaggle. I think it will be a little better